# Why would swapping RAM modules around improve stability?

Tags: windows-10, memory, freeze, troubleshooting

**TL;DR**

Swapping the RAM modules around in my PC appears to fix boot/startup issues, at least for a time.

Is there an explanation for why this would be?  Or even better, does this suggest a proper fix for the problem and if so, what is it?

**Long Version**

I've been experiencing stability issues on a Windows 10 PC.  It starts with hangs (or occasionally, spontaneous reboots) that most typically seem to be triggered by scrolling content within a window (doesn't seem to matter which application).  They occur intermittently at first, but get progressively worse over several days/weeks until the PC no longer boots successfully.  Which is to say that it will POST, start loading Windows, and then hang before it reaches the login screen.

Not really knowing what else to try, the first time this occurred I opened up the PC, reseated the graphics card, and swapped all the RAM modules around (as in, remove them, and then reinserted each one into a different slot).  And bingo, it was back to normal...for a time.  Then the problem reoccurred.

Long story short I've observed that removing and reinserting the RAM modules is what temporarily fixes the stability problem (fiddling with the graphics card, or any other components, isn't necessary).  So far I've always reinserted them in different slots (though I've probably been through enough iterations that they've reached their original configuration at least once by now), but I suspect the trick will work just as well if I just put them back in the same slot.  I'll try that approach next time.

Is there an explanation for what's going on here?  Or even better, does this suggest anything that might be done to effect a proper, long-term fix to the stability problems?

In case it matters, the PC has 6x4GB RAM modules installed.

For those looking for further specs, they are:

- Gigabyte GA-X58A-UD3R Mainboard
- Intel Core i7 980 CPU
- G.Skill DDR3-1600 RAM (4GB * 6)
- Nvidia Titan X GPU

Comment: Can you give any more specs like mainboard, processor, graphics card, (PSU)?
I would think that the swapping did not cure anything, but your findings are coincidental (or can you reproduce the issue in 100% of the cases when unswapped and it works 100% flawless after swapping?)
Did the problem first appear when you changed something (including software) or does it exist since the installation of Win10?

Comment: Sounds more like your firmware configuration is being reset, and switching the modules, is triggering a automatic reconfiguration. I suspect the motherboard, I personally, would replace it

Comment: @flolilolilo - The problem occurred some relatively lengthy time after upgrading to Win 10.  Not sure the exact duration, but long enough that I don't believe Win 10 is itself to blame.  I'm 100% certain that unplugging the computer, opening the case, removing the modules, and reinserting them fixes the problem.  And 100% certain if I do the same process but omit the last two steps, nothing happens (i.e. the next boot will fail).  I too suspected coincidence the first, second, and third time this happened.  After that, I concluded swapping the RAM is indeed doing _something_.

Comment: Look into the [Mainboard's manual](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-x58a-ud3r_v2.0_e.pdf) (for some reason, my browser keeps crashing with that link) and look up how you can manually adjust RAM timings (and perhaps RAM voltage). I have no experience with Gigabyte mainboards, so I'm not sure about their feature-set, but maybe the mainboard tries to auto-overclock the RAMs (and/or the CPU) by the first "normal" boot, being the one **after** the one that is done when power is restored. (so the second after connecting your system to the plug again)

Comment: (addition) then, you could try [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to test your RAM for faults - that's generally a good idea after "playing around" with the RAM-timings.

however, that would not explain why this issue shows up after a lengthy time with no problems.
my second idea would be to update all the drivers - or reverse them to a version from a time where you are sure that the issue wasn't there.

**All of this of course is only my standard procedure for these cases.**

Comment: One module has issues, swapping them put the faulty module as being used after the first one is full. Run a memtest on the modules....http://www.memtest.org/

Answer (score 1):

Swapping the RAM around is not fixing anything.  Either one or more of the memory modules is bad or the memory controller itself is.  The computer is working till it tries to read/write to the bad part of memory.

Put in one module at a time and use a memory testing program like [Memtest86+](https://www.memtest.org/) to check if the RAM is good.  I highly suspect one or more is bad.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect its your memory timings although your memory could also be bad.
First download and install CPU-Z.

It has 2 tabs.
The actually timings and the timings read directly from the SPD on the memory chip.

You need to check all the DIMMs.
Screen capture the results.

Mark down the highest values for each timing at the Mhz you are currently running your RAM.  RAS CAS etc

Go into the BIOS and adjust these values accordingly.